# Cannot pass data from tabBarController to it's viewController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm passing data from main view controller to tabBarController's variable "temp1" and i was able to pass the data but i'm not  able to pass that data to viewController of tabBarController.
I'm getting error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value.But i have data in variable temp1 also i do have "namew" label exist in viewController.Don't know what i'm doing wrong

```
class tabBar: UITabBarController {

    var temp1:String?
    var temp2:String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print(temp1!)  // i can print data


        guard let vc = self.viewControllers?.first as? calcVc //VC of tabBar VC
            else
        {return}
        vc.namew.text = temp1. // error


    }
}
```

Comment: start class names with capital letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `namew` which is nil as the vc isn't yet to be loaded

```
    guard let vc = self.viewControllers?.first as? calcVc //VC of tabBar VC
        else
    {return}
    vc.loadViewIfNeeded() // add this line
    vc.namew.text = temp1
```

Comment: Error cleared with the above changes.But couldn't display the text in the label